# Placing characters on JQuery slider handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Whay I want to acomplish is use icons from fontawesome on my JQuery sliders, so I am pretty much trying to insert HTML code into the a that serves as the container for the handle.

This is my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $("#slider-vertical").slider({
            orientation: "vertical"
        });
        $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
    });

    $('#slider-vertical.blue a.slider-handle').append('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>');

});
```

And this is the HTML for the said slider

```
<div id="slider-vertical" class="blue">zing</div>
```

Weird thing is I tried to target the outer part of the slider and that worked

```
$('#slider-vertical.blue').append('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>');
```

, I don't understand why it won't put it inside the handler.

I expect something like this as output

```
<div id="slider-vertical" class="blue">
    <a class="slider-handle">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? mind show us the output html you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does add the element, which is visible. http://jsfiddle.net/LZx5L/1/ This is your problem

```
 $('#slider-vertical.blue a.slider-handle').append('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>');
```

There is no `a.slider-handle`, it's `a.ui-slider-handle`

```
 $('#slider-vertical.blue a.ui-slider-handle').append('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>');
```

However, There's no reason the icon has to be an `<i>`. Adding the classes to the element is the simplest solution.

```
$('#slider-vertical.blue a.ui-slider-handle').addClass('fa fa-bars');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LZx5L/

Comment: i think that does it indeed! i'll see what i can do with it. what is the deal with <i> anyway?

Comment: so basically i just have to not close the i? or what's the deal? i'm a bit confused

Comment: You don't **need** to close the tag of the element when you create it in jQuery but it doesn't matter if you do. I usually do it longhand: `$('<i>', {'class': 'someclass', id: 'the_id'}).text('Some text')).appendTo('#something');`

Comment: There is no discernible difference between your code and that on the jsfiddle. There isn't enough of your code to explain why the bars won't show on your page, since the code you gave works when used in isolation.

Comment: jonytest.co.nf this is the website

Comment: @morgred I've spotted your actual issue. See my updated answer http://oi41.tinypic.com/33xakip.jpg

Comment: ah, so the id has to be added after the class?